# Flashing in OnPaint

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, mfc, gdi

I have a children of CWind class, where I'm subscribing on OnPaint event:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(MyListBox, CWnd)
    ON_WM_PAINT()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

If in OnPaint handler I draw something simple in window, like border, all is good. But if I'll add `Sleep(50);`(by doing this I simulate some hard drawing operations) my window will be flashing. I cant understand why this happens... May be problem is that OnPaint function is called often, about 2-3 times in a sec.

Update: I am using double biffering: first I draw window content in PaintDeviceContent and then copy this DC to window's DC.

Update2: Here is code:

```
void CDirectionsListBox::OnPaint() 
{ 
    CRect rectClient;
    GetClientRect(rectClient);

    CPaintDC dc(this); // device context for painting

    CDC DCMem;
    DCMem.CreateCompatibleDC( &dc );

    // Draw window here, workign with DCMem

    dc.BitBlt(0, 0, rectClient.Width(), rectClient.Height(), &DCMem, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
}
```

Comment: Please show the code where you copy the device context.

Answer (score 5):

By default, the background is painted by clearing the client area using the background brush.  You want to turn that off.  Handle `WM_ERASEBKGND` and do nothing, since you're going to blit over the top of any existing image anyway.

Also see [How to avoid flicker while handling WM_ERASEBKGND in Windows dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164751/how-to-avoid-flicker-while-handling-wm-erasebkgnd-in-windows-dialog)

Comment: The problem is that flickering occur not each time when `OnPaint` happens. But if I'll increase `OnPaint` execution time - flickering will occur each time.
So I suppose this is somehow connected with function execution time, but why - thats what I cannot understand..
I've tried handle `WM_ERASEBKGND` but flickering remain, doesn't matter am I returning TRUE or FALSE..

Comment: This is the right answer. If it doesn't help you then you have some other unrelated problems with your implementation. Double-buffering in MFC is all about three things: Draw everything into a bitmap (e.g. `CMemDC`), avoid calling the base-class (or make sure the `WM_PAINT` message is sent coupled with the buffered HDC), return TRUE from `WM_ERASEBKGND`.

Comment: @Seekeer: Of course the time you spend in `OnPaint` before the blit affects the flicker, because this determines the time that the erased background is on-screen.  If you both erase and blit during a refresh cycle, the erased background never makes it further than the video card (doesn't go to the physical display).  If there's a delay in between erasure and blit, then the erased screen will appear on the display for a few frames, and be noticable by the user.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your window is flashing is because it's trying to display things that have not finished drawing yet.

When drawing using MFC you'll need to manually double buffer the window you're drawing to if the drawing operation is non-trivial. In essence, what you want to do is to create a drawing context in-memory and draw to that instead. When the drawing is complete you copy what is found in your in memory context to the window context.

Comment: I believe the problem lies in you sleeping in the OnPaint to simulate complex drawing. If you're using OnPaint to draw you want that to return quickly to give control back to the windows message pump. You really should be doing the drawing to your backbuffer somewhere else and in the OnPaint method only blit the backbuffer contents to the window.

Comment: You suggest put "expensive" drawing in helper method and call it async?

Comment: It really depends on your application needs, but potentially yes.

Comment: No reason to make it async.  Just don't the complicated rendering in between erasure and blit.  The best way to avoid this is to eliminate erasure completely, but blitting the old image at the beginning of `OnPaint` would have the desired effect also (at the cost of wasted GPU bandwidth, for the erasure and reblit of existing data)